# IE shadow rendering bug and jQuery

Tags: jquery, png, transparency

I'm using jQuery to "fade in" a certain part of my site. In IE8 the box fades in, but during the fade, the shadow is solid black. After the fade, the image is rendered normally.

The shadow is a PNG shadow.

Is this a known issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a CSS shadow or a PNG shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in how IE handles the 8-bit alpha channel when combined with the opacity filter. The only solution I'm aware of is to make the image an [AlphaImageLoader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969.aspx) filter (as you would for IE 6 to display the alpha channel correctly at any opacity) rather than a background-image.

Comment: I'm not combining anything. I'm using jQuery.

Comment: @Moshe, jQuery uses the alpha filter for opacity in IE < 9. You aren't doing it directly, but it's being done nonetheless.

Comment: @Moshe, I added a link to the AlphaImageLoader specification.